# Regex value returns false when detect symbols within quotes

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I have regex to grab all special characters which are not enclosed between double quotes but when I use the test function it returns `false` for everything.

I'm a beginner to regex, any guidance will be helpful.

[Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/v2gut0/1)

test.html

```
<input 
    class="bg-white appearance-none border border-black rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-black leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:ring-0 focus:shadow-none ring-offset-0 focus:border-primary dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 m-3"
    id="inline-full-name" type="text" [maxlength]="maxChars" [(ngModel)]="newproxyAddr" (ngModelChange)="validation($event)">
```

test.ts

```
public validation(addr: any) {
 
  const checkEnclosedPattern = /[][@()\[\]{};,:.<>](?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/
    
  console.log(checkEnclosedPattern.test(addr.toString()))
}
```

Comment: addr.toString() from where addr value is coming?

Comment: from a input box  (ngModelChange)="validation($event)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Regex101, if you choose ECMAScript as flavor, your regex will not work correctly.

Because the starting `[]` treat as:

> [] empty character class — matches null

I believe you can remove the starting `[]` as you have handled the `\[` and `\]`.

```
[@()\[\]{};,:.<>](?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/fA45qR/1)

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9lab6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Understood ,this works as expected ,Thank you